# apply arithmetic and comparison operators on groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, arithmetic-expressions

I have the following dataframe (df):

```
ID  Age Code
1111    66  C18.2
1111    66  C98.4
1111    66  I50
1111    66  D20
1112    45  C54
1112    45  C54
1113    78  N18.3
1113    78  N18.6
1113    78  N18.2
1113    78  N18.1
1113    78  N18.1
1114    52  C40
1114    52  C19
1114    52  C100
1114    52  C100
```

I would like to first group the data based on ID using `df.groupby('ID')` and then on this grouped data, I would like to apply some arithmetic and comparison operators. If those conditions are met, add a new column (df[risk]) and enter H, otherwise enter L in the new risk column. I would like to apply the following conditions on the grouped data:

`(Age > 65) & ((Code >= C00.00 & Code <= C99.00) | (Code >= N18.1 & Code < N18.6))`

I tried to do for Age using

`df1=df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['Age']>65)`

and it shows True and False for rows depending if condition is met. But I could not add H if it is True or L when it is False in a new column. 
The second part of the comparison is a bit more difficult as Code column contains characters and floating numbers. What I did is that I separated the characters and numbers into two additional columns using:

`df[['Let', 'Num']] = df['Code'].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+)([\d\.]+)', expand=True)
df['Num'] = df['Num'].astype(float)`

and then i can select the data based on conditions using:

`df1 = df[(df['Age'] > 65) & (((df['Let']=='C') & ((df['Num'] >= 00.00) & (df['Num'] <= 99.00))) | ((df['Let']=='N') & ((df['Num'] >= 18.00) & (df['Num'] < 18.60))))]`

The above code writes a new dataframe based on the conditions but if you see my example df, it will only separate rows where the conditions are met (without any groupby feature) but I want all the rows of the same ID regardless of they meet the conditions or not. How could I apply similar thing on groupby object and also add H (if conditions met) or L (if conditions do not met).

I would like to get the following output:

```
ID   Age  Code   risk
1111 66   C18.2  H
1111 66   C98.4  H
1111 66   I50    L
1111 66   D20    L
1112 45   C54    L
1112 45   C54    L
1113 78   N18.3  H
1113 78   N18.6  L
1113 78   N18.2  H
1113 78   N18.1  H
1113 78   N18.1  H
1114 52   C40    L
1114 52   C19    L
1114 52   C100   L
1114 52   C100   L
```

Looking forward for any help.

Comment: It'd really help if you showed how your desired dataframe would look... I'm not clear if you want unique IDS with columns containing criteria or if you're really after something else...

Comment: Hi Jon, I have updated the question and showed also what sort of output I would like to get.

Comment: Thanks - not sure where the groupby is coming into this now? Is every row assessed on its own bits as `1113` would have a both H & L risk for the same age... So it mostly looks lke the risk is purely on the code and age for that row and doesn't need to be taken into account on the ID as a whole?

Comment: Actually, I have to use this conditional criteria to see if there is any entry with H risk is present in any of the rows belonging to a specific ID. Once H and L information is present for every row of every ID, I need to separate ID's including all associated rows where atleast H appear two times and then do further analysis.

Comment: The last code that I have in my post works fine but instead of writing H and L per row per ID, it separates the rows where H condition is met and ignore the L rows. so then data is kind of separated into 2 dataframes which I do not want. Rather than writing a new dataframe, if I could get a way to add another column in df and mention H and L by modifying my last code, that would be what I need.

Comment: Ahhh... then instead of doing `df1 = ...` have you tried: `df['risk'] = np.where((df['Age'] > 65) & (((df['Let']=='C') & ((df['Num'] >= 00.00) & (df['Num'] <= 99.00))) | ((df['Let']=='N') & ((df['Num'] >= 18.00) & (df['Num'] < 18.60)))), 'H', 'L')` ?

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.